# Problem with Web Live Preview with Kendo controls

Tags: telerik, visual-studio-2019

We have a website that heavily uses Kendo controls, which makes it hard to know how the page will look after rendering.  I want to use the "web live preview" extension to visual studio, however i have an issue.  When the page opens, says in the bottom right corner "building tree" or something along those lines and never actually finishes.  Is there a trick to get it to work with Kendo?  I tried it because i got an email from them suggesting we do it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the message you're seeing is "Generating Logical Tree...". The extension is still in Preview, so there's several things that could be the cause of that, but we would like to work with you to try to address them. If you could file an issue on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/), and include any errors messages you see from your browser's console (make sure to include Verbose messages), we can try to dig in. Also keep a look out for updated versions of the extension (it should automatically update) as we're steadily fixing bugs.

Comment: what is your target release schedule like?  It's not necessarily telerik controls i'm having problems with.  Our login page works just fine and it has textboxes on it.